# Alternative ways to check time zone in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, time-zone

Is there a way to verify a user's configured time zone from the command-line? I'm trying to help a third-party user with a time related issue and they don't have access to their "Date and Time Properties" Window (it's explicitly blocked).

I tried checking with the **date** and **time** commands but neither of them show the actual time zone.

Comment: Is there a reason the Date and Time Properties can't be unblocked?

Comment: @TomWij: It could be group policies.  I had to disable it one a bunch of client PCs because people were looking at the calendar to see when holidays were and hitting "OK" instead of "CANCEL" when done.  This REALLY screws up stuff in a timestamped SQL database.

Comment: @TomWij - I don't directly manage the user so I'm not sure what the administrative decision was.  Most of their workstation was locked down so I presume it's indeed a group policy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Timezone is a part of the "systeminfo" command output.

Answer (score 1):

There is a utility in [these MS support tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en) called TimeZone.exe that should fit the bill.  There's not a command in native XP for this.

It is in the registry in

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`

But I couldn't tell you what the names should be, and if they are locked out of date/time I'm guessing they are locked out of the registry too.